# Salesforce stackexchange unable to ask question

Tags: discussion

My user account was removed from stackexchange due to sock puppetry issue.I have asked a query they provided the time suspension period for this  account one day.In future I wont repeat this issue .After the time suspension period of one day also.I am not able ask questions from this account.I have merged this account with another account also

**Guide Me to recover this account**

If i click ask question:

it is showing like

[image]

Please recover this account.In future i wont repeat this issue,I have merged this account with another account also.I have this only one account  in stack exchange.Guide me to recover this account.I want to use this stackexchange in useful manner

Comment: Only a mod can do anything about this. [@AdrianLarson wrote a post about this](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2471/do-not-maintain-multiple-accounts) so I would guess he's actively looking into sock puppet accounts. I'm sure, once he or another mod reads this, they can review the who/what/where/when/why of this.

Comment: All the mods are exceptional at looking at Meta posts, so they'll read this question with certainty. You'll just have to play the waiting game and give them time to review your claim.

Comment: We have not removed your account. You just still have a question ban (which we cannot remove). You have to improve your content quality. The only person who can help you is yourself.

Comment: How do I improve my question.All the existing questions are correct manner.I dont how to improve the old  questions.please guide me @AdrianLarson

Comment: please guide me to edit the previous questions? or shall i delete previous questions @AdrianLarson.Guide me to edit my question this time only

Answer (score 4):

This very Meta post is a symptom of your problematic behavior. If you had simply googled **[stack exchange question ban](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stack+exchange+question+ban)**, you could have learned everything you need to know from the first result. Or even just [google the exact message](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=We+are+no+longer+accepting+questions+from+this+account.+See+the+Help+Center+to+learn+more.).

Please read through ***all the content*** written in this Meta post: **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)**

I cannot stress this enough: ***read the whole thing***. I will cite some relevant content below but you need to put a little work into understanding the system if you want to improve your situation.

---

> An [automatic filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.

**The system has almost surely flagged your IP address as problematic**. Using sock puppets to ask more bad questions likely made the problem *worse*, not better. The more duplicate accounts you open at that location, the more the system's filters will consider your questions low quality.

There may also be *other* users exhibiting the same problem behavior on that IP address. If you know of them, you might point them to this same topic.

---

> ## How do I avoid getting a question ban?
>
> [Read the pages in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly those [about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [the Stack Exchange model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange). Investigate and search before you ask. Put some effort in your questions.
>
> All questions are expected to have some value for later visitors too. So if many of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, closed, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality. Be sure to understand why that happens, and learn from that. Don't simply repost the same question again.
>
> If you're not sure what qualifies as a "good question", there are some hints and tips available:
>
> - [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center
> - [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet
> - [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric S. Raymond
> - [Getting Answers](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) by Mike Ash
>
> To learn about formatting:
>
> - [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
> - [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
> - Try for yourself in the formatting sandbox

That's really important: **Be sure to understand why that happens, and learn from that. Don't simply repost the same question again.**

---

> ## How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.**
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> **Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**
>
> Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.
>
> If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).

Again: **Moderators cannot lift the ban.** I literally cannot help you, nor can any of the other moderators.

The *only* way to ameliorate your situation is to improve your existing content. The change has to come from you. Please don't try to fix all 100+ posts in a day. Take one post at a time, and try to understand how to make it the best possible question it can be. Do that for a few posts a day, and focus on really learning how to be a good citizen of the Stack Exchange network.

---

Also:

> ## My account is in good standing. Why am I still blocked?
>
> The ban also takes in account the IP address. If you browse from a shared computer, or from a location that gives the same IP address to many end users, it's enough that another user who was banned or triggers the ban, will affect everyone else accessing from the same location.

If you are asking many questions from your office, talk to your office-mates and work with them to understand how the system is supposed to work, and make a group effort to improve the quality of content you are contributing to this site.

Answer (score 2):

Do not delete your questions, but rather find ways to improve what you have already posted. How can you improve your questions? Let's just work backwards through your most recent questions:

- [Illegal assignment from Account to String](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160103/illegal-assignment-datatype)

  - Your post does not even contain a *question*. What is it you're asking?
  - Does your error indicate a line number?
- [Null Pointer Exception in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160088/null-pointer-exception-in-salesforce)

  - Asking the same question over and over again isn't going to do you any favors.
- [Trigger Error in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159993/trigger-error-in-salesforce)

  - Again, your post doesn't contain a question.
  - You also don't make any attempt to share what you're trying to accomplish.
  - As I mentioned in the comments, please include error messages and code as text, which makes it significantly more accessible.
- [Date and Time stamp value should be updated in the field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159791/date-and-time-stamp-value-should-be-updated-in-the-field)

  - Your post is full of run on sentences. Try to construct fully formed, grammatical sentences.
  - You use bold *everywhere*. Limit your use of bold text to a small percentage of critical text that you want to highlight.
- [Workflow Rule to Timestamp created/updated datetime in specific format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159771/workflow-rule-to-timestamp-created-updated-datetime-in-specific-format)

  - Again your post does not even contain a question. The format here is *question* and *answer*. Make sure you ***ask a question***.
  - This is another situation where your post seems nearly indistinguishable from an earlier post. Please try to focus on improving your one question to get the best answer, rather than posting multiple questions that are all basically duplicates of each other.

Just looking through your most recent five posts, a few themes emerge:

- Do not post duplicate questions. If you don't get an answer right away, take a look at what you can improve.
- Make sure your *question* posts contain an actual *question*. It should be a full sentence that ends with a question mark.
- Grammar is important. Your posts will be better received if you properly form your sentences.
- Formatting is important. Limit your use of bold to *highlights*. If you bold the entire post it has a negative effect.